# One line for loop to add elements to a list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to remove stop words (from nltk) from my data set but not sure why the one line query is not working:

```
filtered_words = [word if word not in stop_words for word in words]
```

This is what I need to do:

```
filtered_words = []
for word in words:
    if word not in stop_words:
        filtered_words.append(word)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the if has to be at the end of the list comprehension:

```
filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
```

see: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 3):

syntax you want is :

```
x = [x for x in range(200) if x%3 == 0 ]
```

put condition behind for

the syntax you have requires else like :

```
x = [x if x%3 == 0  else None for x in range(200)  ]
```

and this produces an error:

```
x = [x if x%3 == 0  for x in range(200)  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is backwards. 
[appending_word for word in starting_words if word not in stop_words]

---

```
starting_words = ["hi", "joshing", "afflate", "damage"]
stop_words = ["afflate", "K", "books"]
filtered_words = []
'''for word in starting_words:
    if word not in stop_words:
        filtered_words.append(word)
==

filtered_words = [word for word in starting_words if word not in stop_words]'''
```